# SQL query to pull certain data from multiple tables based on values in a third

Tags: sql

I have three tables that look something like this:
**Table 1:**
ID Number
Code
Amount
Indicator (I/A)
**Table 2:**
ID Number
Name
Address
**Table 3:**
Code
AName
AAddress
I need help writing a SQL query that will pull the Name & Address from Table 2 only if the Indicator in Table 1 is an "I", or instead will pull the AName & AAddress from Table 3 only if the Indicator in Table 1 is an "A".
I've been driving myself crazy over this! I've tried various IF and CASE statements, but have not gotten any closer to a solution.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
Select
     Case T1.Indicator
        When 'I' Then T2.Name
        When 'A' Then T3.AName
     End as "Name"
    ,Case T1.Indicator
        When 'I' Then T2.Address
        When 'A' Then T3.AAddress
     End as "Address"


From Table1 as T1
    Join Table2 as T2
        on T1.IDNumber = T2.IDNumber
    Join Table3 as T3
        on T1.Code = T3.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for? With coalesce, the first hit that is not null gets returned. So if we join table2 with the condition one.indicator = 'i' it will be null otherwise, instead giving the value from table3.

```
SELECT one.*, COALESCE(i.Name, a.AName) name, COALESCE(i.Address,a.AAddress) address
FROM table1 one
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 i ON one.id = i.id     AND one.indicator = 'i'
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 a ON one.code = a.code AND one.indicator = 'a'
```

I had to assume that we wanted to join on code in the case of table3.

EDIT: This should at least work for sql server and mysql, if you're looking to solve it for another db type, this could be a suggestion for an approach that could work.

Comment: may need a distinct to eliminate duplicates